# How to translate org-mode tutorial from emacs commands to spacemacs commands?

Tags: spacemacs, fedora-25

I am new to emacs and am learning org-mode on spacemacs.
Most org-mode tutorials use emacs key bindings, but I want to learn the spacemacs keybindings.
For example, [this org-mode tutorial](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html) is intended for emacs users.
So I am trying to translate the tutorial commands from emacs to spacemacs.

The tutorial says "M-RET", and I want to know what the equivalent Spacemacs command is.
So I look it up in emacs help.
describe-bindings says "M-RET" is a keyboard macro:

```
SPC h d b
pattern: M-RET
"M-RET" is a keyboard macro.
Macro: M - R E T
```

The tutorial also says "C-c C-v".
describe-bindings says "Prefix Command" is a keyboard macro:

```
SPC h d b
pattern: C-c C-v
"Prefix Command" is a keyboard macro.
Macro: P r e f i x SPC C o 2*m a n d
```

How to translate a tutorial from emacs commands to spacemacs commands?
Is there a better way to learn spacemacs?

I am running Emacs 25.2.1 with Spacemacs on Fedora 25.

Comment: For those new to Emacs, here is the good tutorial, everything in it worked: orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html

Comment: The tutorial given in the questions used obsolete keybindings.  Here is the good tutorial, everything in it works: orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html